# Which one can I choose? SSH or AMQP?

Tags: c++, networking, ssh, amqp

My application runs in Windows and is implemented using `C++`/`Qt`.

The application will invoke another application deployed in the Linux server which in turn will invoke some third party tools. The Linux server application will send some status updates based on the running of third party tools. Usually the third party application will run for hours and the updates will be sent at various stages. The Linux server may also has to send some files in addition to the status updates and the Windows client will also send some files required for the running of those third party tools.

I planned to implement this in [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/) since file transfers can be done and applications can be executed as well using `libssh2_channel_exec()`. Updates can be sent and received through non-blocking socket transfers. Also the transfers must be secured and they are password authenticated, so I thought `SSH` will conform my requirements.

I also looked into [Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/index.html) of apache which implements the `AMQP`. The messaging seems to be a more appropriate one for my status updates since the updates are less frequent. But I am not so sure about the secured connection, password authentication and also the application invocation.

So, which one can I  choose between these two? Or is there any other better option available? I am not quite used to network programming so any pointers, links regarding this are welcome..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered some web-based solutions like XML-RPC, REST, SOAP or other? Note that you can either have constant network connection and stream updates or just make your client ask for update as often as it needs.

Also, I think that building solution based on some of these protocols will give you easier coding - no need for some low-level solutions when you have great libraries. As for security part, I would consider SSL that is part of HTTPS protocol to be secure enough. Of course you can also do it hybrid style, for example SSH tunel to secure server and use SSH key authorization.

But if you are sure youwant SSH or AMQP  then use first one - I think it has better security. Also, try not using username/passowrd. Instead use mentioned above keys.

Answer (score 0):

Start with SSH, and then consider layering other protocols on top. You can use SSH port forwarding to create a VPN connection to a server, and maybe that will make it easier to use something like AMQP or 0MQ.